# AWS ACM SSL on Single Instance beanstalk with Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to add an SSL certificate through ACM with CloudFront on Elastic beanstalk. But I get redirected to beanstalk URL. I do not have an ELB for Beanstalk. It's a single instance environment. How can I fix the redirect issue?

Thanks

Comment: CloudFront is redirecting you? If so you need to provide full details of your CF setup.

Comment: I am not sure what details do you need. But in short, cloudfront origin in beanstalk, and it has a ssl certificate from acm and a domain from route 53.

Comment: There is no redirection in CF. So clearly you made mistake somewhere.

Comment: I added an alternate domain for the route53 domain.